# Comparing e with geometric series confusion

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is the correct problem: By comparison with the geometric series, show that
$$ e - \sum_{k=0}^{N}{\frac{1}{k!}}=\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}<\frac{1}{N\cdot{N!}} $$

But now I'm not entirely sure where to go. I have tried some things, but I can't see how to connect this with a comparison to the geometric series.

Comment: It should be $\frac 1{N\cdot N!}$ on the right. You are correct, as written, the question is nonsense.

Comment: Ah that's what I thought. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where the geometric series comes from: in the sum
$$\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$$ we have
$$\frac{1}{(N+1)!} \leq 1 \cdot \frac{1}{(N+1)!},$$
$$\frac{1}{(N+2)!} = \frac{1}{N+2} \cdot \frac{1}{(N+1)!} < \frac{1}{N+1} \cdot \frac{1}{(N+1)!},$$
$$\frac{1}{(N+3)!} = \frac{1}{N+3} \cdot \frac{1}{N+2} \cdot \frac{1}{(N+1)!} < \left(\frac{1}{N+1}\right)^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{(N+1)!},$$
and so on.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yep! I was able to get it! Thanks.